# How to get the id value in controller/action/id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an edit application view, and it can be found at the following URL:

http://localhost:17262/Application/EditApplication/1

1 equals the application ID.

Also on the page I have a link that goes to another view to add an assistant for the application.  I want to pass it the application ID so that the new assistant can be "linked" to this application.  How would I get the value of 1 and add it to my action link?  This is what I have in my HTML so far:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Add New Assistant", "Create", "Assistant", new { applicationID = "id" }, null) %>
```

Please could someone advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the default routing settings

```
Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

should do what you want.

you can also pass the id from the controller to the view using the ViewData

```
ViewData["applicationID"] = 1; //or ApplicationModel.Id or whatever
```

and use it in your view

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Add New Assistant", "Create", "Assistant", new { applicationID = ViewData["applicationID"] }, null) %>
```

or in a strongly typed view use the viewmodel to pass the id:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Add New Assistant", "Create", "Assistant", new { applicationID = Model.ApplicationID }, null) %>
```